# How to use FactoryGirl with a model that takes a hash in initialize method?

Tags: ruby, rspec, initialization, factory-bot

Seems simple, but haven't been able to figure out how to get this to work.

In model.rb:

```
def Model
  attr_accessor :width,
                :height

  def initialize params
    @width = params[:width]
    @height = params[:height]
    ...
```

In factory file `models.rb`:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :model do
    height 5
    width 7
  end
end
```

Setting the attributes in the factory method throws an error `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`

Working in Ruby 1.9.3 without Rails, using `Factory.build`. FactoryGirl 4.1.

EDIT: More info:

Using RSpec: `let(:model) { FactoryGirl.build :model }`

Comment: This looks like a standard FactoryGirl definition.

How are you calling `Factory.build`?  Could you post the full contents of your factory definition, including any `after_build` or `after_create` hooks?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This should work with your class:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :model do
    skip_create

    width 5
    height 9

    initialize_with { new(attributes) }
  end
end
```

-`skip_create` bypasses the default `save!` action normally called on new objects.

-The `attributes` method generates a hash you can pass to `new` using `initialize_with`.

Comment: This passes in an empty hash. `initialize_with {{ height: 5, width: 6 }}` passes in the appropriate hash, but the factory returns the hash instead of the model object.

Comment: You're right; there shouldn't be an ignore block. Removing it now.

Comment: How did you ever find this out?

Comment: Would you please add the link to the docs? (preferably to the answer)

Comment: @TylerCollier https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md under Custom Construction

Comment: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#custom-construction